# python create re.compile instance error when regex contain escape character

Tags: python

when create re.compile, return different result when position of escape character

re.compile('[:<>"\]+') -> re.error: unterminated character set at position 0

re.compile('[\:<>"]+') -> re.compile('[\:<>"]+')

python version info : sys.version_info(major=3, minor=10, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

i think these two code is completely same but return different result
so can i catch the reason of them?

Comment: You should use a "raw string", a string literal prefixed with `r`.

Comment: "raw string" won't help here. They stop python literal character escapes - but neither `]` nor ':` are special character for literals.

Comment: @yeony Your second variant is also wrong because "re.compile" interprets the `\:` as plain `:` which means that the backslash isn't contained in the character set.

Comment: @tdelaney My change of the formatting to show the double backslashes in combination with the use of raw strings solves the problem because a double backslash is then received by the regex compiler and interpreted as a single backslash as member of the character set. As already mentioned, this isn't the case even for the second variant of the code in the question because the backslash would just vanish when the regex compiler processes it.

Comment: @tdelaney.  `import re;  re.compile("[\]")` results in exactly the error the OP experienced.  It doesn't matter if Python doesn't escape every character as the re parser views `\` as an escape character in all cases.  That's how `\d' `\s` '\w' etc, work.  
  An re pattern to find a literal backslash character has to be either 4 backslashes in a str, or 2 backslashes in a raw string.  i.e.  `re.compile(r"[\\]")` or re.compile("[\\\\]")`

Comment: I didn't catch the mis-formatting in my comment due to SO/markdown using backslash as an escape character before the edit window closed.  The main point is that the re parser uses backslash as an escape character in addition to how it is used in Python strings as an escape character.

Answer (score 1):

From the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) doc, the backslash is used to escape special characters both in python literals and characters that are used specially in the regular expression itself. You wanted to put a backslash in the character set, but you ended up escaping the terminating `]` character making the regex invalid. By moving the backslash, you avoided both the python and the regular expression special characters.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash character is always an escape character in re patterns, even in positions it wouldn't be causing an escape in a normal Python string.

If it is followed by a character that doesn't have special meaning, that character just acts normally, so in the second example given `re.compile('[\:<>"]+') -> re.compile('[\:<>"]+')`, this pattern will not match on the backslash character, but will still match on a `:`.  This can be tested at [pythex.org](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5B%5C%3A%3C%3E%22%5D%2B&test_string=My%20sentence%20%5C%20Has%20a%20backslash%20%5C%20and%20it%20isn%27t%20matched%2C%20but%20the%20other%20characters%20%3A%20%3C%20%3E%20%22%20are.%20&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

To pattern match on a backslash character you need to escape the backslash character not only within the Python string, but then again for the re parser.

This means that if you are using a standard string, then you must use 4 * '\' `re.compile('[:<>"\\\\]+')`

If you use a raw string, then you need 2 * '\'  `re.compile(r'[:<>"\\]+')`